# Global object within include of an include

Tags: php, oop, include, global

Righty-o

I am fairly new to OOP.

Im using PHP v5+

I have my index.php:

```
<?
include_once('class/includes.php');
$reg = new register;
$action = $_GET['action'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
include('header.php');
if($page):
include($page);
else:
include('home.php');
endif;
include('footer.php');
?>
```

i have my htaccess set up so that the url for each page is foo.com/pagename

Thats fine.

on my classes.php page (foo.com/classes) which as default includes viewClasses.php
//note classes refers to yoga classes rather than OOP classes

so essentially i have 2 levels of includes (index.php including classes.php which includes viewClass.php)

this is my viewClass.php

```
<?
global $reg;
$reg->viewClassList();
echo $reg->classList;

?>
```

For some reason it is not picking up $reg as defined in index.php and therefore is giving me this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function viewClassList() on a non-object in /home/pandazco/public_html/register/viewClass.php on line 3

I hope this explains my problem well enough...

Comment: You should read about [Local File Inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_file_inclusion).

Comment: You should not need to declare `global $reg` there. It is already exposed as `$reg` unless that is inside a function.  However, you have a _much bigger problem_. This is vulnerable to a giant directory traversal attack!  You are blindly including whatever `$page` points to, which could dump your system's password file to the screen.  You must at a minimum, filter `$page` against characters like `../` or remote protocols like `http://` or `ftp://`.

Comment: what would be a better way? just set up each variable (ie)
if($page = pagea): include pagea; endif;
if($page = pageb): include pageb; endif;
if($page = pagec): include pagec; endif;

Comment: @MatTaylor Best is usually to use a whiltelist of possible values `if (in_array($page, array('page1','page2','page3'))`  If $page is not in the array of allowed strings, don't include it.

Comment: Cheers for that, for now its going to be offline hosted locally, but there is a chance it will be attached to the clients website further down the line, will use that, cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are not including the instantiation in your viewClass.php which means that $reg is nothing. This is what the error is telling you.

However I would never use global vars, in fact I am pretty sure there are many lengthy discussions on not using them. Instead I would set a session variable and read from this instead if you need to pass data between different php scripts.

Additionally why are you using $reg as a global anyway? All you appear to do is instantiate it in index.php and try to call it in viewClass.php. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Good point, I just wanted to instance $reg for whatever page is there, so i should do it page by page?

Im making an online registration for yoga classes

Comment: Agree re: globals.  Globals are never necessary.  In fact, they lead to brittle code, and are a sign of doing it wrong.  It's especially egregious in an OOP context where encapsulation is key.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your register class does it is hard to say. I assume from your method names that you are returning a set of data. Assuming the data comes from a database you may not want to keep calling a new instance on each page request, if the data being returned does not change frequently you may find it better to call it once and keep it within a session variable and pull it back as necessary. However again it really depends on what your class does because putting excessive amounts of data into a session is also not a wise move.